# Passing a value to modal

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog

I have a `<table>` and under one its `<td>`, I am printing a different value and there is also a button on each `<td>`. Upon clicking the button, I want to pass the value to the modal. Here's what I got so far:

HTML:

```
<a data-toggle="modal" data-id="123" href="room.html#myModal">
    Check in
</a>
<div class="modal hide" id="myModal">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
        <h3>Modal header</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        Room Number: <a name="roomnumber" id="roomnumber"></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).on("click", ".modal", function () {
    var roomNumber = $(this).data('id');
    $(".modal-body #roomnumber").val(roomNumber);
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jelloshio/hv32v3kq/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are attaching click event on .modal which you have not given for check in.
And to display data in anchor tag you can use .text()

```
<a data-toggle="modal" class="clickThis" data-id="123" href="room.html#myModal">
    Check in
</a>
```

and your js code:

```
$(document).on("click", ".clickThis", function () {
    var roomNumber = $(this).data('id');

    $(".modal-body #roomnumber").text(roomNumber);
});
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hv32v3kq/4/)

Comment: Do you have any idea how to pass the value roomnumber to a servlet? `request.getParameter("roomnumber");` doesn't work @roshan

Comment: Make sure you have roomnumber in the data you are sending to server. Deafult submit will not have roomnumber since it is not an input. Cannot tell for sure need to see the code.